# Fresh new install or keep old version

Tags: updates

After 4 years I'm changing  my hosting. I installed wordpress 4 years ago and updated it ever since.

Now that I'm changing host, I was wondering if my site could benefit in terms of performance/cleaness with a fresh new install (moving wp-themes, images and using the wordpress export-import articles,tags,ecc. tool) or I should just move the old installation to the new host.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing about moving a site and/or "purging" and re-installing a large PHP application that will "clean" anything or have any impact on performance.  The things that matter regarding performance when going to a new host:

1. Database settings and tuning.
2. PHP settings, especially if you can to to PHP 7 and run PHP-FPM with proper pool setup (if on a multi-core host plan with dedicated core resources).
3. Going to SSD storage instead of spinning disks.
4. In general, memory and CPU - do you have enough of both?

A good hosting company will work with you on all of these points.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The fact is that I've installed many plugins in these years, most of them to just try them out, and I think that most of them don't clean everything they've modified when removed.

Comment: ok, if your question is about "cleanness" without the statement about performance, then yes I understand.  I thought you were more worried about performance implications.  Also you mentioned exporting/importing basic WP content (articles, posts) which I would rather avoid at all costs...